# Выбор jre по умолчанию

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

У меня установлены следующие версии `jdk`:

```
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre/bin/java          1063      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-armhf/jre/bin/java          1063      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/bin/java   318       manual mode
```

`Java-7` стоит по умолчанию. Как мне переключиться на `jdk-8` ? Чтобы при вызове `java -jar` срабатывала именно эта версия `java`.

Comment: Если бы это было в Windows, то это бы, скорее всего, решалось изменением переменных среды. Но у вас, я так понимаю, Линукс?..

Comment: @Ksenia да, это так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже, можно выбрать используемую версию следующим образом:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Вам будет предложен выбор из доступных JRE, например так:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
   Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java         1070      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1069      manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

---

Это перевод ответа на вопрос [Setting JDK 7 as default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272187/setting-jdk-7-as-default) на AskUbuntu.